# In Hadoop, Where does the reducer copy its input during the shuffle phase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In Hadoop, the output of the mappers are copied to the reducers during the shuffle phase. the reducer has to copy its corresponding partition from different mappers. Where does the reducer store its input before starting the actual reduce process?

Answer (score 0):

> The map outputs are copied to the reduce task JVM’s memory if they are
>   small enough (the buffer’s size is controlled by
>   mapred.job.shuffle.input.buffer.percent, which specifies the
>   proportion of the heap to use for this purpose); otherwise, they are
>   copied to disk. When the in-memory buffer reaches a threshold size
>   (controlled by mapred.job.shuffle.merge.percent) or reaches a
>   threshold number of map outputs (mapred.inmem.merge.threshold), it is
>   merged and spilled to disk. If a combiner is specified, it will be run
>   during the merge to reduce the amount of data written to disk.

Ref- Hadoop The Definitive Guide Book